# Attach Database to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql

I'm trying to install yet another forum on my local machine, but I have the error

> Failed to connect:
>
> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in
>   database 'master'. Cannot attach the
>   file
>   'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\forum2\App_Data\Database.mdf'
>   as database 'yaf'.

I really need to solve this problem as soon as possible

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How are you trying to create the database?  Is it through the forum's installer?

Comment: Are you connected to the SQL server as sa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I see the error message, it seems that you havent given the permission to the user. Please tick db_owner. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL Server login (or your Window login if Windows Authentication is used) has to be associated with `dbcreator` (or better, e.g. `sysadmin`) Server Role in order to perform `CREATE DATABASE ...` commands.

> Members of the **dbcreator** fixed server
>   role can create, alter, drop, and
>   restore any database.